# Infopath 2010 form issue

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have created one infopath form. There are multiple views. Here it gives an error to publish infopath form to form library. I have deleted all controls, XML files and data connection but still give error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error makes reference to the "Forecasts and impacts" view.  does that view still exist within the infopath document?

i'd check my rules for any references to that view (switch to view) as well

Comment: Thanx for your reply @dfminky, I have deleted that view and controls which are existed in that view, still getting error of this view.

Comment: There might still be a reference to it in the manifest.  If i couldn't find any way around it, i may look into renaming the xsn to a cab and checking the manifest but that can get messy; great for documentation however.